# Images not loading in Applet

Tags: java, image

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Converted Java Game to Applet; Wont load pictures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13771352/converted-java-game-to-applet-wont-load-pictures)

I have a single image for all my ground textures, like a spritesheet but just vertical, and it just gives me the first block (grass) every time. Heres the code for loading and cropping the image:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Screen.tileset_ground.length; i++) {

    URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource("tileset_ground.png");
    Screen.tileset_ground[i] = getImage(imgUrl);


    ImageFilter imgF = new CropImageFilter(0, 26 * i, 26, 26);
    ImageProducer imgP = new FilteredImageSource(Screen.tileset_ground[i].getSource(), imgF);
    Screen.tileset_ground[i] = createImage(imgP);  

}
```

Comment: How many times is it iterating through the for loop?

Comment: 100 times because i just randomely set the tileset_ground array to 100 slots

Comment: What happens if your tileset is less than 100 tiles long?

Comment: unless I change it to zero, because then it can only load one of the images and i get an arryindexoutofbounds exception. obviously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to move the first two lines in the for loop outside of it. You only need to do that step once.

Secondly you need to figure out how many tiles are in your tileset and only iterate that many times.

So maybe something like this?

```
URL imgUrl = getClass().getResource("tileset_ground.png");
tileset_image = getImage(imgUrl);

num_images = HOWEVER MANY IMAGES ARE IN THE TILESET

for (int i = 0; i < num_images; i++) {

    ImageFilter imgF = new CropImageFilter(0, 26 * i, 26, 26);
    ImageProducer imgP = new FilteredImageSource(tileset_image.getSource(), imgF);
    Screen.tileset_ground[i] = createImage(imgP);  

}
```

Comment: I am getting a nullpointerexception at      ImageProducer imgP = new FilteredImageSource(Screen.tileset_ground[i].getSource(), imgF);

Comment: I am guessing it is because the tileset_ground[i] hasnt been created yet...

Comment: and what does tileset_image do?

Comment: Oops I made a mistake. I edited my answer to change the FilteredImageSource line.